# Avatars not showing on phpbb forum

Tags: css, image, phpbb3

I have a PHPBB forum and my avatars aren't being displayed. When I inspect the element the img element is greyed out.
[image: Example]

I can't work out what the problem is, I have tried to edit the css to `display: block` but this doesn't resolve anything. In the settings avatars are also enabled so that isn't the problem.

Comment: incorrect src value. set complete URL

Comment: How can I resolve this, this is handled by phpbb?

Comment: check config file , there may be settled image location directory.

Comment: No there is nothing in the config file..

Comment: do you know where these code is written, file and line?

Comment: No I don't know, additional information, its with many images, not only the avatar, captcha images are also not loaded.

Comment: do u know the code page of this html output

Comment: I am sure, you have image directory error . search in phpBB forum :http://goo.gl/GNO4i4

Comment: I don't have a clue, but I'm wondering that if this problem is located in the theme I'm using or in the original files of phpbb

Comment: I have found many topics regarding this problem, but none of them offer a solution

Comment: IF i go over the source I can see the image ...
http://oi60.tinypic.com/x3wgz.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the image when you hover over the source, I'm confident that you don't have a image directory error.

1. Have you edited many css files?
2. Have you put some `display: none;` lines in any of them?
3. If yes, go over each line (use search function in your IDE) and comment them out, see if it resolves your issue.

Report back with your result.

Comment: Ah finally, yes I have had put some of that line in custom.css, I found the line which was causing the problem, thanks!